# Selenium EventFiringWebDriver : isElementPresent does not work anymore

Tags: selenium, xpath

In order to take screenshots in case of errors, I changed my driver initialization from

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File(FIREFOX_PROFILE_PATH));
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, BASE_URL);
```

to

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File(FIREFOX_PROFILE_PATH));
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
MyEventListener eventListener = new MyEventListener();
driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver).register(eventListener);
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, BASE_URL);
```

My class MyEventListener :

```
public class MyEventListener implements WebDriverEventListener {
...
@Override
public void onException(Throwable throwable, WebDriver driver) {
    String filename = generateFilename();
    SeleniumUtils.captureEntirePageScreenshot(filename);
   }
}
```

It's ok for my screenshots but my test case is broken after 4 tests "isElementPresent".
I don't understand what's happened, my xPath are ok because my script works very well when I retry with my old driver.
It is strange because when I uncomment a line before the first which does not work, at the retry the line works well.

Have you any idea to solve the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Well what error do you now get?

Comment: The problem is on an `AssertTrue(isElementPresent(locator))` : 
java.lang.AssertionError. Very classic but incomprehensible. Why does it work with the first driver but no with the second ?

Comment: And if you debug it? What stacktrace do you get?